# How to tell if SSL_read has received and processed all the records from single message

Tags: c++, openssl

Following is the dilemma,
SSL_read, on success returns number of bytes read, SSL_pending is used to tell if the processed record has more that to be read, that means probably buffer provided is not sufficient to contain the record.

SSL_read may return n > 0, but what if this happens when first records has been processed and message effectively is multi record communication.

Question: I am using epoll to send/receive messages, which means I have to queue up event in case I expect more data. What check will ensure that all the records have been read from single message and it's time to remove this event and queue up an response event that will write the response back to client?

PS: This code hasn't been tested so it may be incorrect. Purpose of the code is to share the idea that I am trying to implement.

Following is code snippet for the read -

````
        //read whatever is available.
        while (1)
        {
            auto n = SSL_read(ssl_, ptr_ + tail_, sz_ - tail_);

            if (n <= 0)
            {
                int ssle = SSL_get_error(ch->ssl_, rd);
                auto old_ev = evt_.events;
                if (ssle == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ)
                {
                    //need more data to process, wait for epoll notification again
                    evt_.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLERR;
                }
                else if (err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE)
                {
                    evt_.events = EPOLLOUT | EPOLLERR;
                }
                else
                {
                    /*  connection closed by peer, or
                        some irrecoverable error */
                    done_ = true;
                    tail_ = 0; //invalidate the data
                    break;
                }

                if (old_ev != evt_.events)
                    if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd_, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, socket_fd_, &evt_) < 0)
                    {
                        perror("handshake failed at EPOLL_CTL_MOD");
                        SSL_free(ssl_);
                        ssl_ = nullptr;
                        return false;
                    }
            }
            else //some data has been read
            {
                tail_ = n;
                if (SSL_pending(ssl_) > 0)
                //buffer wasn't enough to hold the content. resize and reread
                    resize();
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
    ```
    enter code here
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SSL_read()` returns the number of decrypted bytes returned in the caller's buffer, not the number of bytes received on the connection.  This mimics the return value of `recv()` and `read()`.

`SSL_pending()` returns the number of decrypted bytes that are still in the `SSL`'s buffer and haven't been read by the caller yet. This would be equivalent to calling `ioctl(FIONREAD)` on a socket.

There is no way to know how many SSL/TLS records constitute an "application message", that is for the decrypted protocol data to dictate.  The protocol needs to specify where a message ends and a new message begins.  For instance, by including the message length in the message data.  Or delimiting messages with terminators.

Either way, the SSL/TLS layer has no concept of "messages", only an arbitrary stream of bytes that it encrypts and decrypts as needed, and transmits in "records" of its choosing.  Similar to how TCP breaks up a stream of arbitrary bytes into IP frames, etc.

So, while your loop is reading arbitrary bytes from OpenSSL, it needs to process those bytes to detect separations between protocol messages, so it can then act accordingly per message.

Answer (score 0):

> What check will ensure that all the records have been read from single message and it's time to remove this event and queue up an response event that will write the response back to client?

I'd have hoped that your message has a header with the number of records in it. Otherwise the protocol you've got is probably unparseable.

What you'd need is to have a stateful parser that consumes all the available bytes and outputs records once they are complete. Such a parser needs to suspend its state once it reaches the last byte of decrypted input, and then must be called again when more data is available to be read. But in all cases if you can't predict ahead of time how much data is expected, you won't be able to tell when the message is finished - that is unless you're using a self-synchronizing protocol. Something like ATM headers would be a starting point. But such complication is unnecessary when all you need is just to properly delimit your data so that the packet parser can know exactly whether it's got all it needs or not.

That's the problem with sending messages: it's very easy to send stuff that can't be decoded by the receiver, since the sender is perfectly fine with losing data - it just doesn't care. But the receiver will certainly need to know how many bytes or records are expected - somehow. It can be told this a-priori by sending headers that include byte counts or fixed-size record counts (it's the same size information just in different units), or a posteriori by using unique record delimiters. For example, when sending printable text split into lines, such delimiters can be Unicode paragraph separators (U+2029).

It's very important to ensure that the record delimiters can't occur within the record data itself. Thus you need some sort of a "stuffing" mechanism, where if a delimiter sequence appears in the payload, you can alter it so that it's not a valid delimiter anymore. You also need an "unstuffing" mechanism so that such altered delimiter sequences can be detected and converted back to their original form, of course without being interpreted as a delimiter. A very simple example of such delimiting process is the octet-stuffed framing in the [PPP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1662). It is a form of HDLC framing. The record separator is `0x7E`. Whenever this byte is detected in the payload, it is escaped - replaced by a `0x7D 0x5E` sequence. On the receiving end, the `0x7D` is interpreted to mean "the following character has been XOR'd with 0x20". Thus, the receiver converts `0x7D 0x5E` to `0x5E` first (it removes the escape byte), and then XORs it with `0x20`, yielding the original `0x7E`. Such framing is easy to implement but potentially has more overhead than framing with a longer delimiter sequence, or even a dynamic delimiter sequence whose form differs for each position within the stream. This could be used to prevent denial-of-service attacks, when the attacker may maliciously provide a payload that will incur a large escaping overhead. The dynamic delimiter sequence - especially if unpredictable, e.g. by negotiating a new sequence for every connection - prevents such service degradation.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response.